# Reading PHP association array values in javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to generate simple chart from database values. I used AJAX to getting values from database and return this back to javascript. I would like generate chart from this values with canvas, but i don't know how can i read association PHP array in javascript.

@EDIT

AJAX request:

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "execute.php",
    data: {producer: producer, before: before, after: after, name: name},
    dateType: 'json',
    cache: false,
}).done(function(data) { 
    $("#xdebug").html(data);
});
```

PHP result looks like this:

```
$params = array();

foreach(array_unique($dates) as $date) { 
    $params[] = array("date" => $date, "sold" => sumOrders($date, $dbh), "scale" => sumOrders($date, $dbh) * 10);
}

echo json_encode($params);
```

I receive one this array in javascript

```
[{
    "date": "2017-12-01",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-02",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-03",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-04",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-05",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-06",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-07",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-08",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-09",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-10",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-11",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-12",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}, {
    "date": "2017-12-13",
    "sold": "0",
    "scale": 0
}]
```

How can i do that guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is a typo in your ajax code:

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "execute.php",
    data: {producer: producer, before: before, after: after, name: name},
    dataType: 'json', //dataType not dateType
    cache: false,
}).done(function(data) { 
    $("#xdebug").html(data);
});
```

now the response in `data` will be a json object instead, which you can easily use like:

```
.done(function(data) { 
    data.forEach(function (item){
        console.log(item.date);
        console.log(item.sold);
        console.log(item.scale);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude i got now new experience. Thanks for suggest that i have error in dataType. I don't saw it :D

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a JS array back from PHP, it's just like a normal JS array

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "execute.php",
    data: {producer: producer, before: before, after: after, name: name},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
}).done(function(data) { 
    // do something with your array, as in snippet after
});
```

**Edit : typo in your attribute `dateType` => `dataType`**

Exemple looping, but nobody knows except you what to do with it !

```js
 var data = [{"date":"2017-12-01","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-02","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-03","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-04","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-05","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-06","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-07","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-08","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-09","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-10","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-11","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-12","sold":"0","scale":0},{"date":"2017-12-13","sold":"0","scale":0}];
    
    
    for(var i in data){
      console.log(data[i].date);
      console.log(data[i].sold);
      console.log(data[i].scale);
    }
```